# Lisp - How to do Random Permutations

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

I'm fairly new to Lisp and I was wondering what is the simplest way to create a function that given *n* returns an array with *n* elements, with the permutations from *0* to *n-1*, like for example:

```
(random-permutations 5)

#(2 4 3 1 0)
```

Comment: See [sequence permutations in CLLIB](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/cllib/math.lisp#l271).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a vector of length *n*.  Fill it with the consecutive numbers.  Shuffle (e. g. Fisher-Yates).

In order to play with *all* permutations, you might want to take a look at `map-permutations` from the library `alexandria`.